# While Integrating Crashlytics through the Fabric mac app, it is always come error

Tags: ios, crashlytics

While Integrating Crashlytics through the Fabric mac app,it is always come with error while building the app i.e

> /Fabric.framework/run: line 18:
>   /Users/Desktop/DemoCodeApp/Fabric.framework/uploadDSYM: No such file
>   or directory.

Thanks

Comment: When you create a new build, Fabric simulator gives you the instruction- Step by step, Just follow them.

Comment: Have you added the Build Script properly?

Comment: If you right-click on the Fabric.framework and view the package contents, do you see `uploadDSYM`? Can you post a screenshot of the package contents?